# problem with working directory in Spyder and path

Tags: python, variables, path, spyder

I am new to Python. I am using Spyder IDE to write my scripts and run them in Ipython console! I have actually created virtual environment and imported few module to run test script! My problem is that every time I want to run the script to load an image, I have to manually change the directory. I have also added the folder where I have the data to the path directory. However, I can not load the file from default working directory unless point to its directory! I check some solution from OS module like chdir or path.append from sys, but the problem persists. My question is if there exists a way to avoid the manual change each time even if the Spyder opens in default working directory! Is there any difference between Pythonpath and working directory of spyder in this context? I am assuming when the folder is added to path, the script should be compiled regardless of working directory? Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: "*I check some solution from OS module like chdir or path.append from sys, but the problem persists.*" Using `os.chdir` or specifying the full path to the input/output directory *in your code* is usually the way to go. Relying on Spyder isn't portable, and PYTHONPATH is not the correct way. It would be clearer to [edit] your question to show what you did, post a [mcve], and describe how is it different from the expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning Python too and I am finding the best way of working is to have a terminal (I am using Git BASH on Windows) to run the Python code that I write in Notepad++.

For example, I have a script called 'testing.py' saved in c://myPython. In the terminal, I write:

```
/c/myPython
```

This is where my code is saved so when I try to run a script, it'll try to find it here. From here, I can just write:

```
python testing.py
```

This method seems simpler than anything else I've seen and seems to be the way that most turtorials will have you run the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, my question is a different than just running a python code!

Comment: The question is about Spyder. How does suggesting the use of GitBash supposed to help?